# Creating a select component using Blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 7.x and wondering if there is some built-in Blade feature that I am not seeing in the documentation to ease the process of creating a `select` HTML tag.

Assuming my controller action looks like the following:

```
public function index()
{      
  return view('cars.index', ['cars' => \App\Cars::all()]);
}
```

With HTML, I'd manually render the `select` input with the following hypothetical example:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>

<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Assuming the `cars` table has a `name` and `id` column (`id` being a substitute for `value` and `name` being the actual text of the `option`), is there a 'Laravel' or 'Blade' way to render this component? I've seen prior versions of Laravel use some kind of `Form` template tag. What is the modern way of rendering this `select` input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you can use Form.

I would return the model values as an associative array (id => name):

```
return view('cars.index', ['cars' => \App\Cars::all()->keyBy('id')->pluck('id', 'name')]);
```

And then generate a Drop-Down like this:

```
{{ Form::select('cars', $cars) }}
```

**EDIT 1**

As **lagbox** pointed out in the comments, you'll need to install the `laravelcollective/html` package.

Comment: if they install `laravelcollective/html` they can use `Form`

Comment: side note: you can call `pluck` on the builder instead of a collection  `\App\Cars::pluck('name', 'id')`